# Contractible Spaces are Path Connected proof

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification

Problem: Every contractible space is path connected

My attempt:

Let $X$ be contractible. So, $H:1_{X}\simeq k$ , where $k:X\rightarrow X$ is a constant map, $k(x)=x_0$.

In particular, there exists a homotopy $H:X\times I\rightarrow X$ such that $H(x,0)=x$ for all $x$ and $H(x,1)=x_0$ for all $x$.

If $x,y\in X$ then $H_x:I\rightarrow X$ given by $H_x(t)=H(x,t)$ is a path from $x$ to $x_0$. Similarly, there exists a path $H_y:I\rightarrow X$ from $y$ to $x_0$. Hence there exists a path from $x$ to $y$.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: It would be nice to give the path from x to y aswell. But this looks fine to me. (The path from x to y is just the concatenation of the two paths u found.)